# Use prompt to generate table and add content to it based on input

Tags: javascript, html, input, prompt, tabular

I need to use Javascript to generate a table from user input in a prompt window.

This is for homework and we haven't covered things like jQuery or function scripting, all we've done is basic calculation scripts and the teacher has asked that we use a similar method to what we've been taught to solve the issue.

I have Googled and tried to solve it from what I found, but I don't particularly want to use methods we haven't been taught just yet, and the one method I found that does work is far more advanced than what we've done in class. And I just know that if I ask the teacher he won't be very helpful.

This is what I've got so far, and it generates a list of the input times table up to 10, but I need that data to end up in a table, all I need to know is where do I need the document.write tags to generate the numbers into a table?

Can it be done with some simple commands? Or is it more advanced than what we've been taught so far?

```
<html>
<body bgcolor=#66ccff text=#ff6600>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var number = prompt("Please enter a number:");

    for (i=1; i <= 10; i++)
    {document.write( number + " x " + i + " = " + i*number + "<br>");};


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You already use `document.write` calls to output html, for now it is just lines of text with linebreaks but moving to an html table isn't difficult, you should google for `table`, `tr`, and `td` html elements.

Comment: Suppose I enter '3' as the value, what sort of HTML do you want to generate? If you write out the HTML by hand then it might help you to see what to do -- or post it here and we can give more pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this way:

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#66ccff" text="#ff6600">

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var number = prompt("Please enter a number:");

    document.write('<table border="1">');
    for (i=1; i <= number; i++) {
        document.write('<tr><td>' + number + " x " + i + "</td><td>=</td><td>" + i*number + "</td></tr>");
    };
    document.write('</table>');


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Krasimir: Thank you! That's worked. I knew I had to use the tr, td and table tags, I just wasn't sure where to put them in the script!

Answer (score -1):

I just assigned 2 to undefined number so at first run you don't have the error

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var number = prompt("Please enter a number:");

if(number == undefined)
  number =2;

for (i=1; i <= 10; i++)
{document.write( number + " x " + i + " = " + i*number + "<br>");};


</script>
```

jsbin link is here: https://jsbin.com/puvitinaxi/edit?html,output

Comment: Maybe you forget table.